# How can get all cells of UITableView?

Tags: uitableview, uitextfield

I developed custom cell. which have one UITextfield. i want to clear textfield text on UIButton event. UIButton is also in tableView in another section.

i also tried visible cells but it's clear text only visible cells

so how can i clear all cell's textfield?

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was not got all cells but i reload tableView on my Button Event.

**On CellForRowAtIndexPath**

I was set txtField.text = @"";